# How to send bulk emails id into the array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, email

```
$array = array('abc@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com','sdf@gmail.com','wrd@gmail.com');
```

Above code, I entered manually emails. How can I use the user input emails in the field?

I mean,
I have  `<input type="text" name="email[]">` field. Whatever the user enters bulk email in this field I have to send that email to array like below code

```
 $email=$_POST['email'];//emails comes from user input

 $array = array($email);// store in array
 $arrlength = count($array);// count how may emails are in the field

 $subject=$_POST['subject'];
 $mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];
 send($array,$arrlength, $subject, $mailbody);//It will send the value to mail page
```

Comment: you can use `explode()` function

Comment: if user entering with comma then you need to explode() with comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="email[]">
```

PHP:
 what you need is `explode`.But you need to get emails with comma separation from the user.

```
 $emails=explode(",",$_POST['email']);//emails comes from user input

 $arrlength = count($emails);// count how may emails are in the field

 $subject=$_POST['subject'];
 $mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];
 send($emails,$arrlength, $subject, $mailbody);
```

Comment: Did you check this? @Narendra Verma

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr. Lalithkumar, I tried your code I am getting emails but now I am getting issue on $arrlength and error is syntax error, unexpected '$arrlength' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: make sure you have put semi colon in all the lines near to $arrlength

Comment: Yes. that's correct. It's working. Mr.Lalithkumar I just need two information. 1st one is I have more than 1000 emails with a comma. What I will do just copy and paste in the field. Should I need a comma in the explode function? 
2nd one is how many emails we can send from on input field?
If you know the please help me. It will be great appreciated

Comment: If the input has multiple email with comma then you need to use comma in the explode function... And if you are putting many emails then you need to increase the variable length in the php.ini file